# can't detect window width using hook

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, gatsby

I am using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) and [react-hook/media-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/media-query) to detect window width changes.

I think it works fine in most cases, but I notify that it doesn't work in weird way.

Here's my custom hook for all media queries.

```
import { useMediaQueries } from '@react-hook/media-query';

export default function useDetectDevice() {
  const { matchesAll: isMobile } = useMediaQueries({
    screen: 'screen',
    width: '(max-width: 640px)'
  });
  ...

  return {
    isMobile,
    ...
  };
}
```

```
const NewPage = () => {
  const { isMobile } = useDetectDevice();

  return (
    <h1 style={{isMobile ? '2.25rem' : '6rem'}}>test<h1>
  );
}
```

This works if I change window width through chrome or any web browser, but doesn't work if I fresh start the page.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the SSR is breaking the initial calculations. Try adding the [`typeof window != 'undefined'`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) condition or delay a little bit the initial calculation using a `useEffect` hook like:

```
import { useMediaQueries } from '@react-hook/media-query';

export default function useDetectDevice() {
  if (typeof window != 'undefined'){
  const { matchesAll: isMobile } = useMediaQueries({
    screen: 'screen',
    width: '(max-width: 640px)'
  });
  ...

  return {
    isMobile,
    ...
  };
 }
}
```

Of course, tweak the snippet to make it work but get the idea (defining an empty variable and filling it inside the condition or similar).

As I said, alternatively, you can use the `useLayoutEffect` or the `useEffect` (with empty deps, `[]`) hook to trigger the calculations to ensure that the DOM tree is already loaded.

Related issues:

- https://github.com/jaredLunde/react-hook/issues/163